# helper scripts that plan & apply terraform so that no other input are needed

Tags: bash, azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Am working on a project in Azure using terraform to implement rbac in the enviroment, i wrote a code that create azure AD groups , pulll users from azure ad & add them to the group based don the role & assign permissions to those groups, i use many tfvar files in my variable folder. in order to run or apply terraform i have to pass input variable as seen below;

> terraform destroy  --var-file=variables/service_desk_group_members.tfvarss --var-file=variables/network_group_members.tfvars --var-file=variables/security_group_members.tfvars --var-file=variables/EAAdmin_goroup_members.tfvars --var-file=variables/system_group_members.tfvars

i wish to use a script either bash or python to wrap these variables ,so that i should be able to just run
terraform plan.

i have not tried this before , its a requirement that am trying for the first time, if i can have a sample script or if someone can point me in the rigth path how to do it, i will appreciate it

Comment: What have you tried? A bash script can literally be just a list of commands. Put this in a .sh file starting with `#!/bin/bash` and try it.

Comment: Could you rework you question?  Instead of asking for a script, ask how could this problem be solved.  IS the issue you don't like typing?  You need to keep rerunning it?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform provides an [autoloading mechanism](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#variable-definitions-tfvars-files). If you renamed all your files `something.auto.tfvars` then terraform will automatically load them.  Ordering lexical based on filename.  You will have to move them out of the variables directory.  Terraform expects them in the same directory.